# Работа с ini файлами в C++

Tags: c++

Подскажите какой-нибудь сайт где хоть что-то есть рабочее про ini файлы в C++. Не нашел ни один рабочий скрипт. Какие-то левые библиотеки неизвестно откуда и т.д. А именно как работать с ними.

Comment: напиши свой парсер

Comment: Думаю, что у ini-файлов нету общепризнанного формата, так что придётся писать своё решение (парсер) под ваш конкретный формат. В общем, согласен с предыдущим оратором.

Comment: Если формат файла выбирает сам автор, то предлагаю использовать xml или json - для них точно есть готовые библиотеки

Comment: я начинающий C++ программист, я не имею понятия как написать свой парсер и т.д

Comment: Вот и начинайте учиться, раз чужие наработки не нравятся.  

Подумайте, какую именно информацию Вы хотите получать из конфига (это то, что Вы называете ini-файл).

Что должно быть "по умолчанию". Что может изменяться при запуске программы параметрами командной строки и environment переменными.

Теперь придумайте удобный, как для человека пишущего конфиг, так и для программиста (пишущего парсер) формат конфига  и вперед...

--

Может у Вас получится сделать действительно универсальное средство и тогда все с удовольствием будут его использовать.

Comment: >ini-файлы считаются устаревшими аж начиная с Win 95 (20 лет уже практически)

... и задумчиво набрал на клавиатуре `grep mbstring /etc/php5/cli/php.ini` ... :-)

Comment: @DreamChild, качественной информации - "как работать с ini файлами в С++" очень мало, по крайне мере я нашел всего 1 источник и то где все очень сложно написано, хотя сделать можно легче.

Comment: @Дмитрий Астафьев, что такое "качественная работа с текстовыми файлами"? Да элементарная база уровня "читать/писать", плюс совсем немного базовых же знаний на уровне "структурировать мысли в своей голове" и "разбить строку по пробелам". Всё.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если программу предполагается использовать только под виндой, то можно воспользоваться соответствующими функциями WinApi - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/INI_file#Accessing_INI_files

Кстати, а вы уверенны, что Вам позарез нужны секции? Или, например, возможность перечислять несколько значений у параметра? Потому что написать парсер для примерно такого формата

```
Parameter1 = 123
Parameter2 = 456
```

дело на один вечер максимум.

Answer (score 3):

boost::property_tree - ваш выбор.
пример:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <boost/property_tree/ptree.hpp>
#include <boost/property_tree/ini_parser.hpp>

int main()
{
   std::istringstream ini(R"(
   [Badgers]
   weight = 10
   color = Badger are grey and black.
   )");

   boost::property_tree::ptree bar;
   boost::property_tree::ini_parser::read_ini(ini, bar);

   std::cout << bar.get<std::string>("Badgers.weight") << std::endl;
   std::cout << bar.get<std::string>("Badgers.color") << std::endl;

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Вот это более подходящее.

Comment: @Дмитрий Астафьев, а совладаете с этим *ускорителем*?